# Sorting custom List Java

Tags: java, sorting, generics, comparable

I have a custom generic linked list class called SLL.  For the purpose of my program SLL is going to hold Word objects.  In my Word class I have implemented the comparable interface, and defined three comparators.  When I go to compile I get an error when trying to sort the custom list, using Collections.sort().  I cannot for the life of me figure out why. I have included some code below.  The error message states:

```
//There is no suitable method found for sort(SLL<Word>, java.util.Comparator<Word>)



private static SLL<Word> wordList = new SLL<Word>();

//methods to populate custom generic list


private void printDescending ()
   {
       Collections.sort(wordList, Word.frequencyComp1);
       System.out.println("10 Most Frequent");
       printer(false);
   }
```

My class declaration for SLL and a couple methods are as follows:

```
public class SLL <T extends Comparable <T>>
{
    private Node<T> head , tail;
    private int currentSize;
    public SLL ()
{
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
    this.currentSize = 0;
}

public void add (Node<T> entry)
{
    if (head == null)
    {
        Node<T> temp = entry;
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
        currentSize++;
    }
    else
    {
        Node<T> temp = entry;
        tail.setNext(temp);
        tail = temp;
        currentSize++;
    }
}
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, I am on the last phase of my program :(

Comment: And the error ist

Comment: Isin't the error obvious? (Can't even tag you ^ because of your user name)

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I can tag :)

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)

According to this, your list(SLL) must have a List interface.

Comment: this is an assignment, and the professors instructions were to not implement the list interface

Comment: Then you should be sorting without using Collections.sort

Comment: briefly saw a classmates code he was able to do it using something equivalent to: Collections.sort(SLL , Word.frequencyComp1)

Answer (score 0):

```
private static SLL<Word> wordList = new SLL<Word>();
```

As per your code SLL is class and wordList is class object with the reference of word class.

If you want use the sort method of Collection class the wordList object must be collection type object like below:

```
List<SLL<Word>> wordList = new ArrayList<SLL<Word>>();
```

Comment: produced same error message when I changed the declaration^^